# Form Submit button in MVC3/Razor doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, razor, postback

I have a form written in ASP.NET MVC3/Razor.  The form post works perfectly well in Firefox and Chrome, but for some reason in Internet Explorer, the "Submit" button is unresponsive.

To be clear, if any client-side field validations fail, the validation messages are displayed as expected.  But the Model of the view implements `IValidatableObject` and overrides `Validate()`, and if the data should cause a violation of the validation rules, no error message is displayed.  This leads me to believe that no postback is occurring at all.

Any idea why IE would be behaving this way?

**EDIT:** Code snippet (looks pretty run of the mill, no?):

```
@model MyModel
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveMyForm", "Home")) {
<fieldset>
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="submit" />
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: how are you posting to your page? form post? or AJAX? also, you can validate your data going across the wire using FireBug or Fiddler (more details)

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in the `validate` to see if it's being hit or not...

Comment: @gdoron - I set a breakpoint, and it's not being hit.

Comment: @hanzolo - I added a code snippet so you can see... it's a form post.  I used Charles to verify that no data is being sent across the wire at all.

Comment: @Shaul - yea, doesnt look too complicated, is there any validation going on? Client side DOM manipulation (jQuery?) when you view the generated HTML, are there any overlapping forms? basic sanity checks

Comment: Could you provide a narrowed down example allowing us to reproduce the problem? Model, Controller and View would be excellent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracked it down by commenting out sections of the page code and seeing what had to be commented out before the form would work.

The answer was a hidden field of type `char` that had not been initialized, and still had its initial value of `(char)0`.  The html source generated was:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The MyChar field is required." id="MyChar" name="MyChar" type="hidden" value="" />
```

I compared with Chrome, and there the html source was the same, except for:

```
value="�"
```

That's obviously the "char zero" value.  Apparently IE flips out when it gets char 0 and just truncates it to a blank, and then the client-side validation rule that requires `MyChar` to have a value causes a postback failure, with no place to display the error message since it's a hidden field anyway!

(Parenthetic note: I have not decorated this field anywhere with the `[Required]` attribute, so I have no idea why the html is generating a "required" validator - especially seeing as it's a hidden field!)

Comment: Every not nullable property gets "required" by defaults that's the reason  `data-val="true"` is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom field in model that is used in `@Html.HiddenFor` but is not defined in the class, it will render page but submit/post will not work.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.appUser.UserType)
```

Check all model properties and make sure they are defined model class.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the scripts included at the bottom

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```